# SQL How to do check for multiple not nulls, but not create multiple rows in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

in my *where* clause I have the following:

```
  where 
 (
 (O_LN_NMBR is not null) OR 
 (O_DRCTN is not null) or 
 (O_AC_INCHES is not null) or 
 (O_AB_INCHES is not null) or 
 (o_comments is not null)
 )
```

And it is checking each field for not nulls, but the problem is it creates a new row on the query for each field that is not null! How can I have it check for all not null values, but only return it all the not null fields in one one row for my query?

Comment: Sample data, your expected output, and the full current query would help.

Comment: Not sure what your requirement is exactly. Can you post sample data and structure?

Comment: _Columns_, not _fields_...

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you wanna select a row all `not null` column from tables. Then use `AND`

```
 WHERE
 (
 (O_LN_NMBR is not null) AND
 (O_DRCTN is not null) AND 
 (O_AC_INCHES is not null) AND
 (O_AB_INCHES is not null) AND
 (o_comments is not null)
 )
```

Comment: Perhaps what OP wants!